# How can i create a new column that indicates if in a certain household there is a "child" between an interval of age

Tags: r

[image]

Hello, i'm using R

So i come here with the hope that someone can help me with this. I have an id for every household in the data base(id_vivienda is the name of that variable) and also the ages of every person within or without a certain household and i want to create 1 dicotomic variable that take the value 1 if a person within a household has less than 3 years of age.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Assuming your data.frame is named "df" do this:  `df$new_var = df$age < 3`.

Comment: For your example, please provide what your final desired result should look like. For example, clarify if you want *all* members of a household to take the value 1 if one or more persons within that same household is age <3.

Comment: That’s exactly what i want, if someone within the household is age < 3 then assign the value 1 to the new variable only for the people within the household. the thing is that i need to do this to all different households but they are almost 60000 so i don’t know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and `group_by` to group by household. Then, if any `edad` within that household is less than 3, then set the new variable to 1. In this case, `any` will return `TRUE` if any value within the group is less than 3. Adding the `+` in front will make this 1 or 0 instead of true or false.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id_vivienda) %>%
  mutate(nino = +any(edad < 3))
```

A similar approach can be taken with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, nino := +any(edad < 3), by = id_vivienda]
```

**Output**

```
   id_vivienda  edad numper  nino
         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1  1101100202    56      1     0
 2  1101100203    21      1     0
 3  1101100204    24      2     0
 4  1101100204    28      2     0
 5  1101100205    26      3     1
 6  1101100205    26      3     1
 7  1101100205     1      3     1
 8  1101100206    62      2     0
 9  1101100206    36      2     0
10  1101100209    59      4     0
```